# Handlebars.js: empty propetry when assigning to template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js, frontend

When I log, it shows:

```
"names": {
    "en": "X"
},
"images": [
    "https://x.com/1.jpg"
]
```

and the Template is:

```
<div>{{images.[1]}}</div>                       
<div>{{names.en}}</div>
```

But images' `div` is empty.

How to fix this?

Comment: `images` is an **array** with a single value, remove the `.`, and use the first index: `images[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<div>{{images.[0]}}</div>
```

Handlebars syntax is weird, if you are accessing an element in an array, do this:

```
{{images.[0]}}
```

This doesn't work:

```
{{images[0]}}
{{images.0}}
```

But, if the element has a nested property you can do this:

```
{{images.0.otherProp}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>{{images[0]}}</div>                       
<div>{{names.en}}</div>
```

`images` is an array and array index starts from 0.